# I am trying to get marker color according to the color in the column of my dataframe gdf1 but i keep getting an error

Tags: geopandas, folium

```py
def marker_color(feature):
    return feature['Colors']

gdf1.explore(marker_type='marker',popup='Name', marker_kwds={'icon':folium.map.Icon(color=marker_color)})
```

Output from the code :

```
Error : Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: I want to pass name of color from my column named 'Colors' but this function is passing the whole column list at once. How to modify the code so that it passes one color name at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the color in the `style_kwds` parameter of the [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html) method:

```py
gdf1.explore(
    marker_type='marker',
    popup='Name',
    style_kwds=dict(
        style_function=lambda x: {
            "html": f"""<span   class="fa fa-map-marker" 
                                style="color:{x["properties"]["Colors"]};
                                font-size:14px"></span>"""
        },
    ),
    marker_kwds=dict(icon=folium.DivIcon()),
)
```